# Click Button1 and Button2 will change to multiple colour according to order in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, button

When I click button1, button2 will change to red, and when I click button1 the 2nd time, button2 will change to yellow. When button2 is in blue, after button1 is clicked, button2 will turn back to red. My codes are not correct, but I wish to write my codes similar to this.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    
    String[] colorsArray = {"red","yellow","green","blue"};
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        jButton2.setBackground(Color.colorsArray[i]);
}
```

Code Error:

> cannot find symbol
>
> symbol: variable colorsArray
>
> location: class Color

Comment: `Color[] colorsArray = {Color.RED,  Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN,
      Color.BLUE};` then only  `jButton2.setBackground(colorsArray[i]);`

Comment: @JohnJoe Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** your array of colours is in the same class as this method, not in a class named Color, as the code Color.colorsArray suggests. Code fixed

You don't need a `for`loop. You need to store current status for your BT2 and cycle when reached the end.

This way you start on `currentColor == 0`. When you click button, you set red BG, the set `currentColor == 1`. Next time, you set it to yellow. When `currentColor == 4` you set it to 0 to start all over again.

```
// put this outside method, as class member
private final String[] colorsArray = {"red","yellow","green","blue"};
private int currentColor = 0;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (currentColor == colorsArray.length) {
        currentColor = 0;
    }

    jButton2.setBackground(colorsArray[currentColor]);

    currentColor = currentColor + 1;
}
```

Comment: should be  `Color[] colorsArray = {Color.RED,  Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE};` instead of `String[]`

Comment: @JohnJoe How do I get the text of the colour? Like my button is in green colour, and I want to get the text 'green'. I tried this "jButton2.setText((colorsArray[currentColor]).toString());", but I got 'java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0]

Comment: Why you need to get the color from text ?

Comment: @JohnJoe I want to change the button text based on it's background color

Comment: Why you need to use String[] instead of Color[] ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        String[] colorsArray = {"red","yellow","green","blue"};

        for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            jButton2.setBackground(Color.colorsArray[i]);
        }
```